# How to make Telegram Bot reply to a message?

Tags: c++, telegram-bot

[image: photo]

I have a Telegram bot written in C++ but I can't figure out how to get it to reply to messages like the photo
code (Which I have):

```
 bot.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
     bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Text");
 });
```

Can you help with this?

Comment: Which library are you using to implement the bot?

Comment: tgbot-cpp (https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp)

Comment: Just set the reply id? http://reo7sp.github.io/tgbot-cpp/class_tg_bot_1_1_api.html#a97c42bed628892e7644c7e54bd623fc8